# How to wait for two different keys using cv2.waitKey()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I want to implement a function that while cv2 shows some video, it can wait for two different key inputs and respond to them differently.

I'm using this bit of code to wait for a specific key:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Say I want to use a second key 'w' and respond to that key differently, my first attempt was:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
elif cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('w'):
    print('w is pressed')
```

But it did not work very well, I have to keep pressing w for a period of time until the program responds.

Any suggestion how to do it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, the waitKey method is called multiple times. You should use a variable instead to store it's result and check it multiple times:

```
pressedKey = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if pressedKey == ord('q'):
    break
elif pressedKey == ord('w'):
    print('w is pressed')
```

The reason behind the waiting is that both function calls read the keyboard buffer so the second branch executed only if the software receives the w key right after the evaulation of the first branch.

Comment: Nice explanation, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

if k == ord('q'):
    break

elif k == ord('w'):
    print('w is pressed')
```